# How can I use command 'at' with Non-interactive style

Tags: linux

Maybe I can use a script file like this:

`at -f script_file now`

but how to assign args to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at does not have -f switch.
you can use it like following:

```
echo "sh script.sh" | at 11:00 PM
```

Comment: It's a good idea. I am sure at have -f switch in man page. `-f file Reads the job from file rather than standard input`